# Power BI - Convert Week Number to Month of the year

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I got this sample table below.

| Ticket Number | Week Number | New Status Date | Month Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 39 | 01-Oct-2021 01:42:26 AM |  |
| 2 | 39 | 01-Oct-2021 01:42:26 AM |  |
| 3 | 39 | 01-Oct-2021 01:42:26 AM |  |
| 4 | 39 | 01-Oct-2021 01:42:26 AM |  |
| 5 | 39 | 01-Oct-2021 01:42:26 AM |  |
| 6 | 40 | 06-Oct-2021 01:46:57 AM |  |
| 7 | 40 | 06-Oct-2021 01:46:57 AM |  |
| 8 | 40 | 06-Oct-2021 01:46:57 AM |  |
| 9 | 40 | 06-Oct-2021 01:46:57 AM |  |
| 10 | 40 | 06-Oct-2021 01:46:57 AM |  |

I need to get the **"Month Name"** column filled on the basis of **"Week Number"** using Power BI.

Comment: It's seems that you need to generate calendar table and check there, also you'll need year. Weeks are different from to year.

Comment: Yeah, what could be best possible solution to achieve this, any page or code to refer?

Comment: You can generate date table as described here:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6756/power-bi-calendar-table/

Comment: Why not get the `Month Name` from the `New Status Date` column?  Or is it just a coincidence that the `Week Number` corresponds to the `ISO weeknumber` of the `New Status Date` column?

Comment: "Week Number" column is not dependent on "New Status Date" may be we need to get the current year and then calculate the month name on the basis of Week Number given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear.

Assuming you want to get the

- Month Name from the date of the first day of the week given by the week number
- and the week number is computed as an ISO week number,

Then I would first add a Custom Function to compute the relevant Date:

```
//fnDateFromISOwn
//compute date of the first day of the week given an ISO weeknumber
//if the Year is not entered, it will default to "this" year
//Year must be a full year: eg 2021 vs 21. The latter will not be interpreted as the year 2021.

(wn as number, optional year as number) =>
let  
    yr = if year = null then Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) else year,
    wn1Start = Date.StartOfWeek(#date(yr,1,1),Day.Monday),
    w1 = if Date.AddDays(wn1Start,3) < #date(yr,1,1) then Date.AddDays(wn1Start,7) else wn1Start

in Date.AddDays(w1, 7*(wn-1))
```

Then you can add a custom column in your main code:

```
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Month", each 
        Date.MonthName(fnDateFromISOwn([Week Number], Date.Year([New Status Date]))))
```

**Source**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

On the other hand,

- if there is a relationship in that the weeknumber always corresponds to the `New Status Date`,
- and it is still an ISO weeknumber,
- and you still want the month name corresponding to the date at the start of that week

then you can use the simpler formula where you merely compute the previous Monday to the `New Status Date`, and obtain the MonthName from that date.

```
Date.MonthName(Date.StartOfWeek([New Status Date],Day.Monday)))
```

Comment: this what I was expecting...couple of more challenges to before I finish my report..I am not able to schedule the power Bi refresh, posted the question here - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649540/not-able-to-schedule-the-dataset-refresh-in-power-bi-for-jira-reports] ..any suggestions?

Comment: @techmaster Which solution did you use?  On your other question, I can't really help. But if you type the error line into a google search, some MS authored help files for that problem pop up.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can achieve result using power query

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Ashok\Power BI\Stack Overflow\data_24_oct_21.xlsx"), null, true),
    Data_Sheet = Source{[Item="Data",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Inbox Number", Int64.Type}, {"Week Number", Int64.Type}, {"New Status Date", type datetime}}),
    #"Inserted Month Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Month Name", each Date.MonthName([New Status Date]), type text)
in
    #"Inserted Month Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

The major question is, how would you like the month number to be returned? A week could fall in 2 months. Would you prefer to return the month the week starts in? Or perhaps the month the week ends in?

The general idea for a good date table you can find here:
https://gorilla.bi/power-query/date-table/

But if you just want the weekly table, you may need to make a join on both week number and year number using logic like here:

https://gorilla.bi/power-query/date-table-with-monthly-increments/

Instead of incrementing by month, you can increment this one by week using

Date.AddDays( _, 7 ) instead of Date.AddMonths( _, 1 )

Hope that helps!

Rick